# Skipping over values in a generator function

Tags: python, generator

I am writing a generator function that gives me alpha-characters, like so,

```
def gen_alphaLabels():
    a = range(65,91)
    for i in a:
        yield chr(i)

k = gen_alphaLabels()
for i in range(26):
    print k.next(),
```

This yields,

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

This works....

I would the function to skip over some characters that in a donotInclude list. I could do this is outside the generator, like so,

```
k = gen_alphaLabels()
donotInclude = ['D','K','J']
for i in range(26):
    r = k.next()
    if r not in donotInclude:
        print r,
```

This yields the desired result of skipping over 'D','K' and 'J'

```
A B C E F G H I L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Is there a way include the logic relating to skipping over characters in the generator function? Some thing along the lines of

```
def gen_alphaLabels():
    a = range(65,91)
    for i in a:
        r = chr(i)
        if r in donotInclude:
            yield self.next()
        else: 
            yield r
```

Comment: A note on a part of your code that's not directly related to your question: To consumer your generator, you should probably do `for c in get_alphaLabels(): print c,` rather than looping on a range and manually calling `next()`. This will be important when your generator yields an unknown number of values!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without using continue + a little shortening of code:

```
def gen_alphaLabels(donotInclude):
    for i in range(65,91):
        char = chr(i)
        if char not in donotInclude:
            yield char
```

Comment: @Bonifacio2 Well I think the answer differs enough to warrant its own spot. Just a matter of opinion.

Comment: The first version of your answer was nothing more than a copy of RickyA's. Now that it adds some value I'm revoking my downvote.

Answer (score 9):

`continue` to the rescue:

```
def gen_alphaLabels():
    a = range(65,91)
    for i in a:
        r = chr(i)
        if r in donotInclude:
            continue
        yield r
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer on this. I am accepting Joowani's answer as it is the one with less number of line and more concise

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.uppercase` instead of `chr` (I also used a list comprehension instead of `if`):

```
import string
def gen_alphalabels(exclude):
    labels = [c for c in string.uppercase if c not in exclude]
    for label in labels:
        yield label
```

List comprehension above may be a matter of taste, but it does allow us to use `yield from` in Python 3.3, making it even more concise:

```
import string
def gen_alphalabels(exclude):
    labels = [c for c in string.ascii_uppercase if c not in exclude]
    yield from labels
```

Comment: It seems silly to me to do a list comprehension, then immediately yield from the list. I'd either use an explicit loop and yield individual values (as the other answers do) or simply return the list!

Comment: @Blckknght, I'm assuming he wants to use the generator somewhere where he'll be yielding its values alternating with something else. As for the list comprehension, I find it more readable like this, but I did say I think it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Blckknght, Oh, and as I said in the answer, with the list comprehension you can do `yield from labels`, which I think you'll agree is nicer than the `for` loop.

Comment: My point is that there's no need to make the function a generator if you're just going to yield from a pre-made collection. You can replace `yield from labels` with `return labels` and it will work as well or better in every situation. Generators are only a good idea if they're saving effort by computing things only as they're needed.

Comment: @Blckknght, if that is your point it would have been more useful to make it on the question, to suggest a better solution to nitin's problem. The list comprehension is a red herring; it is no more a pre-made collection than the range from 65 to 91. Still, thanks for making me think about it. I know generators are most useful in hefty computations, but I always vaguely thought of their ability to keep state as a nice general feature. I never used them for anything serious though, so it's entirely plausible to me that you're right.

Comment: you could change the list comprehension to a generator expression to avoid precomputing the list

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any variables in your gen in this case.

```
def gen_alphaLabels():
    for i in range(65,91):
        if chr(i) not in donotInclude:
            yield (chr(i))
```